# Truthful budget partitioning

Tags: game-theory, voting-theory, social-choice-theory, auction-theory

Suppose there is a budget $M$ that needs to be partitioned into two projects $A$ and $B$. There are two players, where the first player prefers to allocate $pM$ to A and $(1-p)M$ to $B$ (i.e., it maximize its utility), while the second prefers  the allocation $qM$ to A and $(1-q)M$ to $B$. Suppose the preference is a smooth function. Is there a fair mechanism (for instance taking the average of both proposals) that is incentive compatible (or close to one)? Can the revelation principle be applied here?

Comment: What is the revelation principle ?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Smoothness seems like a very weak quality, do you perhaps mean [single peakedness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_peaked_preferences)?

Comment: Yes. That's a reasonable assumption.